# Why won't the Bing Maps for Visual Studio 2013 C++ open up?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, bing-maps

I've done everything listed below to get the Bing Maps API to get working. I've also created a Basic Bing Map key for my use, but when running the app the screen shows a map and a red cross over it.

1. Added the Map tool to the project
2. Changed the build configuration to Win32, as it said that it sint compatible with x64 ( I have windows 8.1 64 bit running though )
3. Added reference to  "Bing Maps for C#, C++, or Visual Basic" to the project
4. Added the following piece of code :

   ```
   <bm:Map Credentials="INSERT_YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY" x:Name="myMap" 
       MapType="Aerial" ZoomLevel="12"
       Width="600" Height="800">
       <bm:Map.Center>
           <bm:Location Latitude="46.227480" Longitude="-122.192955" />
       </bm:Map.Center>
   </bm:Map>
   ```
5. Inserted my Bing Map Key into the required position.

All the above was listed on the site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh846489.aspx but was unable to get the Bing Maps working.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: C++-cli?  As in managed C++?

Comment: I am using the C++ Blank ( windows ) template for the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the Bing Maps API is country or region restricted. Changing the country settings of my Windows system made the API work as intended.